# Pihole in a IPv6 setup: How to reliable distinguish certain clients for them to be grouped?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, pihole

In my local home network, I want to have IPv4 and IPv6.

I want to use my pihole as primary DNS.

I furthermore want to group clients so that certain devices can bypass the blocklist and issue their requests upstream. (As in: friends who don't like google ads links being broken).

I don't want to configure an alternative DNS server on each client itself.
I don't want to disable IPv6 and just use IPv4.

How can I achieve that?

---

What I am trying to achieve is very straight forward for me in IPv4 world:

In an IPv4 world, I:

- assign each of my clients a static IPv4 address within my network due to their mac address
- have a pihole running with a static IPv4 address issued by my server
- have my DHCP server announce the pihole address as DNS server to each client
- within pihole configuration, I can now add clients to certain groups

---

Now, I also want to allow IPv6 traffic and here I am mainly confused.

Static IPv6 addresses suddenly aren't really a thing. Everything is autoconfig. That is fine. I handled it so that DHCPv6 server announces the ULA of my pihole, which I hope won't change, as DNS server and each clients that issues their DNS requests at my pihole.

Yet in my router, I cannot assign clients to a specific IPv6 address.

My router isn't even in charge of issuing out IPv6 addresses, it merely announces the prefix of all the networks, and each client now makes up their own IPv6 addresses (plural), and those temporary ones really make everything else a mess. As how can I reliable determine which IPv6 address belong to which client?

How can I group clients for my pihole in a IPv6 setup? Is there an IPv6 way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

> Static IPv6 addresses suddenly aren't really a thing. Everything is autoconfig

They're definitely a thing. Nothing forbids them.

It would be a bit silly to ask one's guests to manually type in static addresses into their phones, though, whether it's IPv6 or IPv4.

> Is there an IPv6 way of achieving this?

You would configure your router to *not* announce the prefix as "autonomous configuration", while announcing the "managed configuration" flag. This would force clients to use DHCPv6 exclusively, both for IP addresses and for DNS information. (DHCPv6 IA_NA address leases work just like DHCPv4, except there's an even bigger emphasis of what DHCPv4 calls "client IDs" and DHCPv6 calls "DUIDs", i.e. the leases are distinguished by something else than the raw MAC address.)

The problem with that is that Android still refuses to support DHCPv6 so your guests' devices will become IPv4-only if you do that.

If your guests only want Internet access and don't care about local devices (like chromecasts etc), having a second "Guest" VLAN with its own subnet and its own Wi-Fi SSID would be another option.